# Using a method with an array

Tags: java, arrays

I believe this code works but I have no idea how to execute it with an array. I wanted to change for example `{1,2,1,6,2}` to `{2.0, 6.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0}` with this method.

```
public double[] intToDoubleArray(int[] anArray) {
    double [] anArrayDouble = new double[anArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length/2-1; i++) {
        anArrayDouble[anArray.length-i-1] = anArray[i];
    }
    return anArrayDouble;
}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: hint: `i < anArray.length/2-1` is wrong, you're skipping half of the array

Comment: Thanks for hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it

```
double[] doubles = intToDoubleArray(new int[]{1,2,1,6,2});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doubles));
```

I think the condition of the for should be `i < anArray.length`.

Otherwise

inside the loop, 2 casts

```
anArrayDouble[anArray.length-i-1] = anArray[i];
anArrayDouble[i] = anArray[anArray.length-i-1];
```

and for arrays with odd size cast the value in the middle

Comment: Thanks for the help!